# Уместна ли постановка двоеточия в предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Уместна ли постановка двоеточия в данных предложениях? Так как здесь причинно-следственные отношения.
1) Ты прав: наши возможности ограничены.
2) Он открыл заднюю дверь: девушка вся дрожала.
3) Дай мне попить воды: у меня пересохло горло.
4) Не надо паниковать: машина не заведется.

Answer (score 1):

Существуют три случая, когда между частями сложного бессоюзного предложения нужно поставить двоеточие:

1) если вторая часть указывает на причину того, что описано в первой части, например: В развитых странах средний класс решает исход выборов: он составляет большинство населения. В это предложение можно вставить союз ПОТОМУ ЧТО;

2) если после первой части следует пояснение того, о чем идет речь в первой части, например: Напишите план работы: что нужно закупить и подготовить, с чего требуется начать, в какие сроки возможно завершение проекта» или Как все московские ваш батюшка таков: желал бы зятя он с звездами да с чинами (Грибоедов). В эти предложения между частями можно вставить союз А ИМЕННО;

3) если вторая часть имеет значение дополнения, и перед ней можно вставить союз ЧТО, например: Да я хотел вчера доложить: бороны починить надо (Толстой). В некоторых случаях, кроме этого союза, в предложение можно добавить и пропущенное сказуемое И УВИДЕЛ или И УСЛЫШАЛ, например: Он заглянул в комнату: за столом сидел человек и что-то быстро писал.

В №1,3,4 двоеточие уместно, так как можно задать вопрос "какая причина?".
В №2 - если он открыл заднюю дверь, потому что девушка дрожала - то тоже уместно.

Comment: во в втором предложении имеется в виду, что он открыл дверь и увидел, что девушка дрожит

Comment: Тогда двоеточие подходит по третьему правилу (можно вставить "и увидел").